# HTML - Newline char in DIV content editable?

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

I am storing content in the database, for example:

```
Hello
This
is 
Text
```

and when I pass that to a textarea, it stays with the new line breaks. But if I pass that text to a div with content editable, it would stay like this:

```
Hello This is Text
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks for this question. I was tired of banging my head around but could not find a solution for this.

Comment: [Prevent contenteditable adding <div> on ENTER - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18552336/104380)

Answer (score 152):

Set a style on the div: `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fPv6S/

Comment: This answer deserves so many more thumb-ups. If anybody needs info on `white-space` (I personally went with `pre-wrap`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: or even `white-space:pre-line`

Comment: This style makes div output newlines as newlines, but if you copy and paste the `contenteditable` area, the newlines are ignored.

Comment: this question is about contenteditable, not about textarea

Comment: It doesn't work in chrome on android for some reason? is this a bug? I think chrome creates divs to make new lines :(

Comment: I tried `word-wrap: break-word;` but `white-space: pre` works for me

Comment: The question says contenteditable, your fiddle uses textarea, they are completely different - this answer should be ignored.

Comment: Don't be dismayed by the inapplicable fiddle. The solution suggested works for editable elements. `pre` preserves the line breaks and indentation but it doesn't wrap. `pre-line` preserves the line breaks but not the indentation, and it wraps. `pre-wrap` preserves the line breaks and the indentation, and it wraps.

Comment: @user2677034 the textarea is just so you can update the contents of the div.

Comment: @Explosion Pills - I fully understand that, I repeat: this question is about contenteditable, not about textarea.

Answer (score 20):

*To add some info on [@Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills) correct answer and extract some info from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):*

The CSS `white-space` attribute is there to help:

### **pre:**

```
white-space: pre
```

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at
>   newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.

This might result in unwanted horizontal scrollbars as shown in the example!

### **pre-wrap:**

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline
>   characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

As [@ceremcem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1952991/ceremcem) pointed out the line breaks at the end of the box will not be transferred when the text is copy-pasted, which makes sense since these line breaks are not part of the text formatting but rather of the visual appearence.

### **pre-line:**

```
white-space: pre-line
```

> **Sequences of white space are collapsed**. Lines are broken at newline
>   characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #000;
    width:200px;
}
.pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
.pre-wrap{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.pre-line{
   white-space: pre-line;
}

.inline-block{
    display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<h2>
pre
</h2>
<div class="pre" contenteditable=true>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet doesn't have a meaning but here comes 10 white spaces:____          ____</div>

<h2>
pre-wrap
</h2>
<div class="pre-wrap" contenteditable=true>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet doesn't have a meaning but here comes 10 white spaces:____          ____</div>

<h2>
pre-line
</h2>
<div class="pre-line"  contenteditable=true>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet doesn't have a meaning but here comes 10 white spaces:____          ____</div>

<h2>
Chrome FIX
</h2>
<div class="pre-line inline-block"  contenteditable=true>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet doesn't have a meaning but here comes 10 white spaces:____          ____</div>
```

### **EDIT 08/14/2018:**

In Chrome you might experience troubles: Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will generate a new `<div>` inside your contenteditable. To prevent that you can either press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or set `display: inline` to the contenteditable `<div>` as seen in the fiddle.

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: the white-space: pre-line fixed an issue for me that ONLY happened when pasting from clipboard in chrome. It was only adding divs in that case, pressing shift + enter or enter was adding lines <br> as as expected. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Really great answer. I hope SO never dies. Answers like this make humans hard to replace.

Comment: it still generates divs for me..

Answer (score 5):

Try this......

```
var patt2 = new RegExp("<div>","g");
var patt3= new RegExp("</div>","g");
var patt4= new RegExp("<br>","g");
var z=x.replace(patt2,"\n").replace(patt3,"").replace(patt4,"");
```

That will do it...

Answer (score 1):

You could search and replace newlines with `<br />`.
http://jsfiddle.net/fPv6S/1/